# sim900a sms take long time to arrive

Tags: arduino, sms, gsm, sim900

i have trouble with my **SIM900A GSM**
i can send **one** SMS successfully ("arrived in less than one minute")
but when i send *another SMS after first one* (delay more than one minute "it's not for bulk purpose") the **second** message take about **15 minutes** or more to arrive to destination device.

in the same time i'm sending sms my phone to the same destination it's arrive directly all sim-card from the same operator

i have powered the gsm with 5v,2A power so i have no power  problem.

any suggestion will be great

i'm using arduino
this my code :

```
Serial3.println("AT+CMGF=1"); 
delay(1000);
Serial3.println("AT+CMGS=\"+96279XXXXXX\""); 
delay(1500);
Serial3.println("my message");
delay(1000);
Serial3.println((char)26);
delay(1000); 
Serial3.println();
delay(5000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is an issue related to network. Try switching to another network.

As far as the modem accepts your request for sending sms and replies back with `+CMGS` response including the a number, it has performed its job well.

SMS are not meant to be a real time communication and operators delay them due to several reasons.

Comment: i solved this problem.
it's appear when i'm sending message from operator to another 
but when i send message to sim in the same operator this delay disappear.

Comment: Ok. Thats what i mentioned in my answer. It is from the network side. Most probably if you use another network then your messages to another networks might be fast too!